# Response body in reactive spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have a problem with getting a response body with a reactive spring. The service that I'm integrating with can have a different JSON body in response, so I cannot have a DTO that I can map the response to, so I was trying with String.
To check the solution for now I have mocked a simple server with SoapUi to return code 400 and JSON :

```
{
   "errorCode" :  "code",
   "errorMessage" : "message"
}
```

and I would like to be able to log in in console in case of having an error, so here is part of my code:

```
                .bodyValue(eventDataDto)
                .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess((response) -> {
                    if (response.rawStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Sending request failed with status: " + response.rawStatusCode() +
                                " with error message: " + response.bodyToMono(String.class);
                    }
                })
                .doOnError((throwable) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
                })
                .block();
```

but the response that I'm getting is:

```
Sending request failed with status: 400 with error message: checkpoint("Body from POST http://localhost:8095/test/ [DefaultClientResponse]")
```

I was trying to use subscribe, map, and flatMap on that mono, but the only result was that I was getting a different class type on that error message, but nothing close to what I'm looking for.
I would appreciate any help with getting the response body in any form, that I could use its content.

EDIT WITH ANSWER:
A minute after posting it I have found a solution:
So I have tried with subscribe on mono:

```
                .bodyValue(eventDataDto)
                .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess((response) -> {
                    if (response.rawStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
                        Mono<String> bodyMono = response.bodyToMono(String.class);
                        bodyMono.subscribe(body -> {
                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                    "Sending request failed with status: " + response.rawStatusCode() +
                                " with error message: " + body);
                        });
                    }
                })
                .doOnError((throwable) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
                })
                .block();
```

I completly forgot that Mono will not give a result until subscribed.

Comment: Can you add the complete code that performs the call? Will the JSON be nested or have a single depth level?

Comment: It can be nested, it can be a single level.

Comment: Nevertheless, the 400 hints for an issue with the request itself, not with handling the response. That is why I was asking for the complete code.

Comment: 400 is the code that I intentionally giving back from SoapUi just to enter that if.

Comment: Is the response subscribed to ?

Comment: @SB this was the solution that I was missing. I simply forgot that you have to subscribe to Mono. The post was edited with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the proper result as your `HTTP` call succeeds (go-through) but returns a 400 ~ *Bad Request* response code which is a full concise HTTP response (which is the correct response you have configured as per your description in the OP).

In order to have the response body retrieved, either being the proper response body on a successful (200) or unsuccessful (400) response, you should use:

- Either the `toEntity` operator
- Or the `bodyToMono` one

Here down how your call chain would look like mapping the error response content using `bodyToMono`:

```
webClient.get()
.uri("some-uri")
.bodyValue(eventDataDto)
.exchange()
.flatMap((response) -> {
    if (response.rawStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
        return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(errorContent -> "Sending request failed with status: " + response.rawStatusCode() + " with error message: " + errorContent);
    } else {
        return response.bodyToMono(String.class);
    })
.block();
```